# Toggle the button name on click in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have an array of objects. So for every object, which has subItems, I'm trying to add a button to it. On click of the particular button, the name of the particular button should toggle between 'Expand' and 'Hide'. I'm displaying them using map.

```
export default function App() {

  const [button,setButton] = useState([
    {pin: 'Expand', id: 0},
    {pin: 'Expand', id: 1},
    {pin: 'Expand', id: 2},
  ]);

  const dataObj = [
    {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    {
      title: 'Service',
      subItems: ['cooking','sleeping']
    },
    {
      title: 'Contact',
      subItems: ['phone','mobile']
    }
  ];

  const expandFunc = (ind) => {
   // toggle logic here
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        dataObj.map((arr,ind) => (
          <div>
            <span>{arr.title}:</span>
            {
              // console.log(ind)
              arr.subItems && 
              <button onClick={() => expandFunc(ind)}>{button[ind].pin}</button>
            }
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how the output looks -
[image]

If I click on service button, then the button name should toggle between 'expand' and 'hide'. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also need another state like `Toggle` and `expnadFunc` can be handled like this;

```js
const expandFunc = (ind) => {
    let tmp = [...button];
    tmp.map((arr, index) => {
      if (index === ind) {
        return (arr.pin = arr.pin === 'Toggle' ? 'Expand' : 'Toggle');
      }
      return arr;
    });
    setButton(tmp);
  };
```

Comment: this creates two copies of the `button` array. use @mickl or vivek's solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your state by determining new `pin` based on current state, try using `Array.map`:

```
const expandFunc = (ind) => {
    const togglePin = oldPin => oldPin === "Expand" ? "Hide" : "Expand";
    const updatedButtons = button.map((btn, index) => 
        ind === index ? { ...btn, pin: togglePin(btn.pin) } : btn);
    setButton(updatedButtons);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this, I'll also suggest combining dataObj into button state, and using key while mapping elements in React helps to skip them in the rendering process making your site faster.

```js
export default function App() {

  const [button, setButton] = useState([{
      expanded: false,
      id: 0
    },
    {
      expanded: false,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      expanded: false,
      id: 2
    },
  ]);

  const dataObj = [{
      title: 'Home'
    },
    {
      title: 'Service',
      subItems: ['cooking', 'sleeping']
    },
    {
      title: 'Contact',
      subItems: ['phone', 'mobile']
    }
  ];

  const toggleExpandFunc = useCallback((ind) => {
    // toggle logic here
    setButton([...button.map(btn => btn.id === ind ? { ...btn,
      expanded: !btn.expanded
    } : btn)]);
  }, [button]);
  
  return ( <
    div className = "App" > {
      dataObj.map((arr, ind) => ( <
        div >
        <
        span > {
          arr.title
        }: < /span> {
          // console.log(ind)
          arr.subItems &&
            <
            button onClick = {
              () => toggleExpandFunc(ind)
            } > {
              button[ind].expanded ? 'Expanded' : 'Hide'
            } < /button>
        } <
        /div>
      ))
    } <
    /div>
  );
}
```